# Can't auto rotate in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios6

In an app i'm maintaining there's a rotate that should happen in portrait and portraitupsidedown mode. (all the rotation are enabled in the summary panel.)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

or

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

No matter what I tried I couldn't get the rotate to accure i ios 6

Things I've tried so far:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
NSInteger mask = 0;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
return mask;
}
```

I tried putting this in my appdelegate:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

But I'm getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Tried putting this in my delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    if (self.window.rootViewController) {
        UIViewController* presented = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presented supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return orientations; 
}
```

I read all the discussions about it and the deprecations of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation but i still can't get it to work.

I'm about to lose it

Comment: Try to create one category and handle the orientation. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Can you please provide a way \ some code to do so?

Comment: remove your methods and add the code and let me know -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
   
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

Comment: and also change the app delegate method to this -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

Comment: i still can't get it to work.

Comment: where is the `–shouldAutorotate` method?

Answer (score 1):

My application targeted from IOS 5. I used shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method (by default) for IOS 5 device. And categories UINavigationController to handle the orientation for IOS 6.

```
#import "UINavigationController+Rotation_IOS6.h"

    @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {

            return YES;
    }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        if([self.visibleViewController isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"SampleViewController")])
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

    }

    @end
```

Comment: I added the above to my UINavigationController sub class, I can see that `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is getting called but the orientation still won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target properties...look like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}
```